# Update JSON file with data from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I don't have a clue where to start to do this.
I have a form in AngularJS, and I want it to append the data send through it to a json file. I know AngularJS it's just client-side, so my problem is on how to handle the data that the form is sending.
The workflow i'm looking for is simply:

Angular Form -> Send through ¿POST? -> ??? -> Data added to file.json

What could I use to handle a POST from AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a server backend like Node.JS, PHP, Python or Ruby etc.

The server will handle the HTTP post and in your case append the data to a json object.

It doesn't matter if you are using Angular or not, still its an HTTP POST :-)

In Node.JS + express.js 3 you can do

```
var express = require("express");
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies
```

So if you post {"name" : "john" , "surname" : "may"}

```
app.post('/MYPOSTLINK', function(req, res) {
    var name    = req.body.name;    // Get name from body of the incoming data
    var surname = req.body.surname; // Get surname from body of the incoming data
    res.send(200, {});              // what response to send back
    console.log("Your name is " + name + " " + surname);

});
```

Comment: php would be almost perfect for that task. use file_get_contents, json_decode, add the data, the save the json_encode of modified array.